# When building a report, the option to add a row-level formula is missing

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

When building a report, the option to add a row-level formula field is missing from the Columns pulldown menu:

[image]

The profile of the user building the report has appropriate permissions. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_formulas_row_level_limits.htm&type=5):

> "With or Without" custom report types (like Accounts with or without
> Contacts) don't support row-level formulas. The **Add Row-Level Formula**
> button doesn't appear.

Many custom report types involve a "join" of two entities. If the relationship between the two entities is optional, this translates into "with or without" custom report type.  For example, an Account may have 1 or more related Contacts or it might have none:

[image]

which yields this custom report type

[image]

Given this report type, a row-level formula cannot be added via the report builder. As an alternative, you can add a formula field to the parent or child object in question.