# Incoming chats per hour in a report

Tags: formula, reporting, formula-field, custom-reports, report-formula

I am looking for a way to capture the number of incoming chats we get per hour for a particular month. For example : The number of incoming chats per hour for the month of November. Is this achievable through the chat transcript report type or via any other way ? Business requirement : This is required for audit purposes.

Comment: Do you just care about hour in the day? Or the average hourly rate over that span?

Comment: Primarily, it would be per hour everyday in November. An average count would be an additional good to have metric !

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't have firsthand experience of chats myself (assuming they're the ones described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_report_on_sessions.htm&type=5)), but if they have a "Created Date" field, that seems the most promising direction for reports.

You can group those in reports by setting up a "row level formula" like the following, which displays the day of the month and the hour of the day:
[image: Row-level formula example]

Note that if you're *not* looking for per-hour precision, you can also do this without a row-level formula, using "Group Date By..." when you have the date in question in one of the group rows.
[image]

Comment: Hey thank you for looking into this. I am actually using the Chat transcripts custom report type for this. It wouldn't allow me to create a row level formula due to this reason : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/389687/when-building-a-report-the-option-to-add-a-row-level-formula-is-missing. I'll attempt to create a formula field on the parent object using the formula you gave above.

Comment: Formula field should also work, yes; the field name will look like "CreatedDate" instead of CREATED_DATE there, and the function *names* might not match either exactly, but the underlying logic should be the same.

Comment: Hey, I tried creating a formula field with return type number using : (DAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) & (HOUR(TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate)) but i guess i am doing something incorrect here. Any ideas ?

Comment: The "&" is a concatenation: it works on text, not numbers. So you need to convert the "day" and "hour" function outputs to text, via the "TEXT(whatever-you're-converting)" function. And then if you really want the result as numbers instead of text *afterwards*, use the "VALUE(whatever-you're-converting)" function.